# Function input used as string

Tags: r

```
saving_ggplot <- function(name = 'default', plotname = last_plot()) {
  image_name = paste(name, ".png", sep="")
  ggsave(image_name, plot = plotname,
         scale = 1, 
         dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
}
```

This is my function which saves a ggplot. However, I for the life of me cannot figure out how to take the name argument as a string.

for example if someone runes `saving_ggplot(FILENAME, PLOTNAME)`

it will just say no object FILENAME. In python I can just capture it and use it as `str()`, but using `as.character` or `toString` in R still doesn't work.

---

**Error**:

> ```
> saving_ggplot(weightvsageTEST, weightvsageplot)
> Error in paste(name, ".png", sep = "") : 
>   object 'weightvsageTEST' not found
> ```

---

Successful call using ggsave:

```
ggsave('weightvsage.png', plot = last_plot(),
       scale = 1, 
       dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you include the actual code which tries to call `saving_ggplot` with `FILENAME` as a parameter?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, included the error message for example.

Comment: Also added a successful one using ggsave

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the point of my question.  Is `weightvsageTEST` even defined somewhere?

Comment: no that's the point, I'm trying to use the input argument as a string and I don't know how to do that. I want to take whatever the user types in, for example weightvsageTEST and convert that to a string for the filename that gets created.

Comment: I got it...so you want the name of the variable itself to become a string, and then that gets used as the filename, is this right?

Comment: yes so for example if the user has a plot called test1, but he wants the file to get saved to testsuccess, he would type function(name = testsuccess, plot = test1), and it would get saved as testsuccess.png

Comment: I think you just want `saving_ggplot("testsuccess", plot = test1)`?

Comment: What is the value of `weightvsageTEST`?  Is it defined anywhere?

Comment: yes, but i don't want the user to have to type in quotes was the idea. So that they can just type the file name saving_ggplot(testsuccess, plot = test1) and my function converts the testsuccess to a string (adding the quotes). But I don't know if that's even possible

Comment: There is no weightvsageTEST, I'm just trying to figure out if its possible to take the function argument and turn it into a string rather than an object, but doesn't seem doable

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this.  If the first parameter expects a string filename, then you should be passing a string filename, either as a literal or as a character variable.

Comment: it's just so I don't have to type the quotes to be honest. I guess it's not really a good idea.

Comment: Try `name <- deparse(substitute(name))` as the first instruction of the function..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substitute()`:

```
saving_ggplot <- function(name, plotname) {
  image_name = paste0(substitute(name), ".png") # paste0 removes need for sep arg
  ggsave(image_name, plot = plotname,
         scale = 1, 
         dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE)
}

saving_ggplot(foo, p) # saves foo.png
```

Alternately, if you want to stay within `tidyverse` [quasiquotation syntax](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html), use `enexpr()` instead:

```
enexpr(name) # instead of substitute(name)
```

Data:

```
N <- 100
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n=N), y=rnorm(n=N))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_smooth()
```